# Why does the Angular CLI prompt stopped working when initializing a new project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-schematics, angular-cli-v7

I have just installed Angular CLI. When I run `ng new project-name` on my command line, I get a prompt asking about installations of angular-router and CSS setup. However when I run the same command to create other projects, I no longer have the prompt instead the application is just scarffolded. How do I get the prompts to display again?

Comment: You're probably using two different versions of the CLI. These prompts were introduced recently.

Comment: How do I make sure I have only one version?

Comment: `ng v` displays the version.

Comment: Ok, I just ran `ng v` and I get this: Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64

Comment: OK, what is your question? *when I run the same command on other projects*: `ng new` is used to **create** a project. So how could you run it "on other projects"?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write "when I run the same command to create other projects"

Comment: Have you tried running `ng new` from a different shell? I ran into the same issue when using Git Bash, but the prompts work when using Windows Command Prompt and Powershell.

Comment: Yes I did this and it finally worked